# Is there a way to avoid converting Swift from 2.2 to 2.3 or 3 using Xcode 8?

Tags: swift, xcode

I upgraded the Xcode's version to Xcode 8.0, the error that I'm getting is that it forces me to convert the syntax, before the update I'd 2.2 version, but now it requires the version 2.3 or 3.0, and when I try to convert with the Xcode converter, it breaks the entire project (too many errors, and the converter commits lot of mistakes).

Is there a way to use the 2.2 version without upgrading ?

Comment: It may take a little while but you are better off upgrading to Swift 3 since everything will be moving to Swift 3 from this point forward.

Comment: Or just keeping using Xcode 7 until you are forced to upgrade.

Comment: You can install both versions of xCode. Use the 2.2 version on xCode7 if your deadline is urgent. Otherwise, you should update your source code to 3.0.

Comment: @rmaddy Depending on how many libraries you use within your company upgrading to Swift 3 may be no small thing. Where I work our Swift 3 upgrade requires updating libraries from 100+ developers, and we've taken the stance that APIs should be revised to conform to Apple's new style guidelines so it's not simple tweaks. We're working diligently on it but still shipping 2.3 code as it's a gargantuan effort.

Comment: @rmaddy it's relatively huge project, it's a lot of libraries that need to be upgraded. So it'll take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 8 you can upgrade to Swift 2.3 and very nearly everything will stay the same.  Your project shouldn't break and your changes should be minimal.

You'll need to go into the target's build settings and set the option `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` to `Yes`, which will allow you to keep compiling Swift 2.3

Note that the Xcode parser will complain while indexing about various things that aren't Swift 3 compatible, but the warnings will go away once you build successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have upgraded to Xcode 8, it will always ask you to convert to either `Swift2.3` or `Swift3`

@par above shown you how you can just keep compiling on `Swift 2.3` using the `Use Legacy Swift Language` and likes what others comments on your question, you will have to upgrade it sooner than later.

However, to answer your question of avoid the converting to `Swift2.3` or `Swift3`. The way I am using is download the old `Xcode7.3.1`. You can look for the download [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/). Do not replace your Xcode8 but just maybe drag it onto desktop or another directory.

I have some project that depend on other libraries and also previous client project. Therefore I found that using `Xcode7.3.1` to open such project is easier and more convenient.